# Google OAuth Verification branding for YouTube

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm currently going through the process of getting our app approved for usage of some of Google / YouTube apis sensitive scopes. Everything has been going well until recently a branding issue came up.

We have a button with the text '<Approved Icon> Sign in to YouTube'. Clicking this button opens the OAuth verification flow to grant our app access to specific scopes.

After the first 'Issue' with our use of branding, I contacted the YouTube branding team, to ensure complete compliance. I fixed all issues, and they gave me the go ahead for perfect compliance. I resubmitted this information to google's OAuth team, and they said there's still an issue. For 3 weeks we've gone back and forth with me saying essentially 'what's the issue', and they respond with 'the issue is it doesn't meet the branding guidelines' with no actual resolution.

[image] [image]

I've gotten this same response with very little changes each time I've asked a quesiton
[image]

Looking for any wisdom about what I might be doing that doesn't meet the branding guidelines, that both me, and the YouTube branding team are missing. (colors are the same)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I finally got Verified after several attempts just like you. A few tips:

- To sign in and request YouTube scopes, you need to follow the [YouTube Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/branding-guidelines), NOT the standard [Sign-In Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines?hl=en#g%20signin-social-scopes). It's actually not intuitive for me, but you have to use the YouTube Logo to initiate the sign in (the Logo is the little arrow and the text 'YouTube', and you must download it from the YouTube Branding page).
- Make sure to follow all the Requirements section: don't alter the logo, make it visible but don't make it the most prominent element on your web page, etc.
- In my case I had to add the legend 'YouTube is a trademark of Google LLC' and a Limited Use disclaimer in the app and in the privacy policy (this was suggested by the verification team for my use case) [image: Limited Use Disclaimer]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you provide a screenshot to help me explain the last part?

Comment: @jax i've just updated the third point

Comment: Thanks. I finally got approved. Luckily, it didn't have anything to do with point 3. I just replaced the Google sign in with a Youtube sign in button.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information. Can you provide a screenshot of login button which is approved?

Comment: @BurakAybi you can find them in the [YouTube Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/branding-guidelines), under **YouTube Logo**. You can choose (and download) the logo that better fits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why the Trust and Safety team continues declining going to the next level is because 2 things:

1-The logo should not be altered according to their YouTube [guidelines](https://www.youtube.com/howyoutubeworks/resources/brand-resources/#logos-icons-and-colors) And the wording "Sign in to" may no be compliant for them as well as using 2 different red colors in the logo (based on the images you are sharing above).

2-The link attached to the logo in question may drive end-users drive to sites outside of [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/howyoutubeworks/resources/brand-resources/#partners-and-advertisers).

These are the most common recommendations as well as the ones you may already know such as the ones from the YouTube [branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/branding-guidelines)